# What happens if I strncat onto a string without a null terminator?

Tags: c, string, security

**SET UP:**

Given this sort of code:

```
char myString[4];
printf("%s\n", myString);
strncpy(myString, "hi", 2);
printf("%s\n", myString);
strncat(myString, "h123", 2);
printf("%s\n", myString);
```

This will print:

```
 KU�
hiU�
hiU�h1
```

**WHAT I EXPECTED:**

In my mind, myString is a pointer to an allocated spot in memory that looks like this:

```
MEMORY:  [random][random][random][\0][random][random][random]....
PRINTED: [random][random][random][\0]
```

It adds a null pointer to the memory in the fourth spot after the beginning of the string

After strncpy:

```
MEMORY:  [h][i][random][\0][random][random][random]...
PRINTED: [h][i][random][\0]
```

It changes the first 2 characters to be hi and does not add an \0

After strncat:

```
MEMORY:  [h][i][random][h][1][2][3][\0]...
PRINTED: [h][i][random][h][1][2][3][\0]
```

It looks for the \0 after the beginning of the string then removes the \0 and adds its own string as well as a \0 at the end.

What I expected did not occur.

**QUESTION:**

1. What is being printed in there?
2. Which part if what I expected is an incorrect understanding?

**NOTE:**

Now, I understand that this undefined behavior and it should be avoided, but I am asking this question from the perspective of trying to understand all possible exploits that could be used on given code.

I am not looking for the proper coding practice. I am looking for an understanding of what exactly is going wrong.

**EDIT 1**

I do understand that the docs say that its undefined behavior and from a developers perspective one must just avoid the possibility nasal demons.

But from a exploiter's perspective, something is happening here and this may not just be a bug, but instead it may be a security flaw that can be understood in a deeper manner such that a consistent exploit may be formed. I am hoping for this deeper level of understanding. of

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: The initial value of `myString` is all "random" bytes (or whatever junk happens to be in memory), so your initial assumption is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `memset` to 0 on `myString`?

Comment: Regarding `strncat(myString, "h123", 2);`, it appends the first `2` (in this case) characters of source to destination, plus a terminating null-character. This is why you don't get `2` and `3` copied and printed.

Comment: There is no assumption or requirement that a `char` array is going to be used to hold a 0-terminated string. Automatically adding termination would be very unlike how C works.

Comment: Also bear in mind that if you use `static char myString[4];` ,  the entire space will be populated with the zero value of char type, ie null character.

Comment: Removed C++ tag; you'd just use `std:string` in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my mind, myString is a pointer to an allocated spot in memory that looks like this:

```
MEMORY:  [random][random][random][\0][random][random][random]....
```

Maybe in your mind it does, in reality it will look like this:

```
 MEMORY:  [random][random][random][random][random][random][random]....
```

In fact, as the comments say, the characters are not random but indeterminate. Most likely they will be the remnants of previous stack frames that occupied but you don't know.

When you allocate a char array on the stack, no nul bytes are put in. It just increments the stack pointer by 4 and that's it.

**Edit**

Sorry, I leaped in without reading the whole question.

```
strncpy(myString, "hi", 2);
```

The above line copies an h and then an i and then stops because it has copied two chars. If it were sensible, it would just copy the h and then a `\0` but it isn't.

`strncat` is a bizarre function that should probably be consigned to the fiery pits of hell. It goes along to the end of the first string and then adds up to n characters from the second string and a terminating `\0`. The n has no relevance to the size of the buffer to which you are copying and which you can therefor overrun.

```
strncat(myString, "h123", 2);
```

There's no guarantee that your first string has a `\0` anywhere (as already discussed), so it will copy the h and the 1 to an indeterminate memory location.

Comment: Thanks. so, if I printf'ed the undefined string alot it would potentially give me strings longer than 4 characters so long as it never hit a null in memory? Also, is this my main/only mistake?

Comment: And to be exact actually it's not `[random]` but `[indeterminate]`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  That is a good point to be noted.. There is a big difference between random and inderterminate.

Comment: And the C standard doesn't mention a _stack_, even if most implementations are using one.

Comment: in my code strncat does add h1 to the printed string though.

Comment: @Rorschach You are right, I just described (partially) strlcat. I'll fix the answer. As I was writing the original I was thinking "this doesn't seem as bizarre as I remember it".

Comment: `strncat` appends the first 2 (in this case) characters of source to destination and a terminating null-character

Comment: @Jonas thanks for the correction. I must have really been low on caffeine when I wrote the `strncat` part of my answer.